# How to pivot a pd dataframe with 'duplicate' indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like the following:

---

[image: Current DataFrame]

---

Essentially it tracks the # of moves for each unique product id during different shifts; shifts are numbered 1 to 4, days are numeric 1-7. Every shift has only unique product id's, but when I pivoted with 'SHIFT' as the index and 'DAY' as columns, it gave me a duplicate index error.

I'm having trouble pivoting it so the index is the shift number, and columns are grouped by day. essentially I want it as the following:

|  |  |  | DAY |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 |  | 2 |  | 3 |  |
| SHIFT | PRODUCT_ID | #_OF_MOVES | PRODUCT_ID | #_OF_MOVES | PRODUCT_ID | #_OF_MOVES |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Putting it in a pivot table didn't work for me, because I didn't want to apply an aggregation function to the data. I tried pivoting it normally but realized that I'd be using the 'DAY' values as columns, and I'm a little confused on if that were possible to do, and if so how I'd go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: your transposing. this will not work

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"day":[2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3],"product_id":[165,177,182,210,211,213,222,285,308],
             "no_of_moves":[145,18,108,6,12,54,100,3613,301]})


print(df.head())

moves = df.pivot_table(index='day', values='no_of_moves', \
columns=['day','product_id'], aggfunc='sum')
print(moves.T)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, just had to change 'day' in columns to 'shift', thank you!